# Name-Field in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, textfield

How can you make a TextField, that knows it's a Name-Field?
I need the Phone to suggest the User His Name when he taps my TextField.
Any ideas how to do that in SwiftUI?

Thanks for your help!
Boothosh

Comment: It looks like the OP wants the name to be suggested as an auto fill — if so, probably still a SwiftUI question.

Comment: @jnpdx This is what I was trying to say... I'll edit my question so its easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be referring to one of the `textContentType` options.

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textFieldContent = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("User name", text: $textFieldContent)
            .textContentType(.givenName)
    }
}
```

In this example, the system will suggest a given name for the field based on the contact card set to be the device's owner. On iOS, you can see a list of the `UITextContentType` options [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype). On macOS, there's a similar list [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextcontenttype), albeit with many fewer options.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for :)